# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Virtualbox error

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm attempting to run an Android emulator from my Asus laptop, but I've run into some issues.

I intend on using Genymotion, but VirtualBox gives me this error.

" Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Android 6.0.0 tablet-phone.

VT-x is not available. (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6} "

I've looked around a little bit but? I'm still lost. Not sure if it affects anything but I can't access VB's acceleration settings tab either, it's greyed out and unclickable.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

take a look in the BIOS, Look for an option named “Intel Virtualization Technology,” “Intel VT-x,” “Virtualization Extensions,” “Vanderpool,” or something similar. Enable the option and select “Save and Exit” or the equivalent feature to save your settings changes and reboot your computer.